# Omnipascal "'.vscode' is not recognised as an internal or external command"

Tags: vscode-extensions, freepascal, omnipascal

I keep getting this error when I 'Tasks: Run Test Build'. Has anyone have a way to fix this? I'm using FreePascal if that helps.
thank you in advance.

[image: error message]

I looked through the OmniPascal settings section in Visual Studio Code and could not find anything to help. The .bat file didn't help either

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Are you sure the dot (.) in ".vscode" should be there? Have you tried without it?

Comment: the folder name starts with that dot